# CKEditor 4 library is not detected by Wysiwyg module

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, installation

The Wysiwyg installation instructions tell me to

> Extract the archive and copy its contents into a new folder in the following location:
>   sites/all/libraries/ckeditor
>
> So the actual library can be found at:
>   sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js

These 2 conditions are met, however in the overview of editors, the CKEditor is now red. So it sees something is there, it's just not right.
What can be wrong? where should i be looking to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The WYSIWYG module is not compatible with CKEditor 4, because CKEditor 4 uses double quotes `"` around it's version string, where CKEditor 3 used single quotes `'`. This breaks the version detection regex in the WYSIWYG module.

You could use CKEditor 3, like Bruno suggests, or you could patch the WYSIWYG module like described here https://drupal.org/comment/6790812#comment-6790812.

In `editors/ckeditor.inc`, replace line `81`:

```
if (preg_match('@version:\'(?:CKEditor )?([\d\.]+)(?:.+revision:\'([\d]+))?@', $line, $version)) {
```

with:

```
if (preg_match('@version:[\"|\'](?:CKEditor )?([\d\.]+)(?:.+revision:[\"|\']([\d]+))?@', $line, $version)) {
```

If you're not bound to using the WYSIWYG module, you could also use the [CKEditor module](https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor).

Comment: This is not entirely true as the dev version does support Ckeditor 4 versions.  We are currently running it on several sites.  See https://www.drupal.org/node/596966

Comment: Not realizing how old this post was the original answer was correct at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Try an older version of the editor, some newer doesn`t support by the wysiwyg module. Look at the name of the .js data file.

Comment: Great, that was it, thanks. V3.6.6.1 gives no problems

Answer (score 1):

You can too use the "dev" branch of the "wysiwyg" module.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  Is there a particular post in the issue queue that says that this has been patched in dev branch?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/596966

Comment: To elaborate, to use the CKeditor 4.x library with the wysiwyg module, you need to use the wysiwyg 7.x-2.x-dev module. You can view the exact supported editors in conjunction with this module at https://www.drupal.org/node/596966. Otherwise, the stable release of wysiwyg hasn't been updated since 2012 and only supports CKeditor 3.x libraries.

Answer (score 0):

wyguf seak is correct the older version WILL work. go to http://ckeditor.com/download/releases and 3.6.1 and that will work for you.

The latest version did not work for me, so I went for older versions

Comment: Is it an answer or comment to another answer? With reputation, you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, and to comment on answers you find incomplete. When you write an answer, it should be a full, independent answer, not something that makes no sense without another answer.

Comment: My apologies, please can you remove it. Or I can, I thought my answer was helpful. Apologies.

Comment: Best way is to edit, update and make it better. If there is something not yet covered in other answers, probably you could just update yours to look less like a comment? Hint: Who said what has little to no importance; only technical aspects really matters. And if you agree with something, make sure it's obvious what is it, without scrolling back to other posts :) Your answer was not downvoted, it's not terrible. It might be better - that's all.